# Define an unnsigned CHAR in PHP

Tags: php, types, integer, imagemagick, int

A simple simple question but i cannot find the documentation on the php site.

I am working with ImageMagick and i am exporting pixels as CHAR

```
$pixels = $im->exportImagePixels(0, 0, $im->getImageGeometry()['width'], $im->getImageGeometry()['height'], "RGB", Imagick::PIXEL_CHAR);
```

I need to define new pixels and i want them to be of CHAR type.
When i use var_dump on the sigle pixels PHP recognize them as integers.
Now i see that php does not have a CHAR data type, so i want to define a two byte unsigned integer like this:

I have pixel defined as $pixel = 134; ranging from 0 to 255

I want to define the corresponding char like that:

```
0xFF & $pixel
```

It doesn't work.

Anyone has an idea why? or what can i do with that?
I tried to use the PIXEL_FLOAT datatype but it's really heavy and it crashes my script on bigger pictures.

Thanks anyone.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: If you want find control of data types, PHP might be the wrong approach.

Comment: Doesn't give me an error, when i assign $oldpixel = $newpixel and $oldpixel is a char and $newpixel is an int, i get the value -127 or 0, basically the image turns black.

I am just using the Imagick class, i did that with other languages, but i need to do it in php because it has to run on a web server

Comment: What does `$im->exportImagePixels()` return? An array, I believe: http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image2.html#export_pixels?

Comment: Exactly, is an array, you can specify the data type of the elements, beetween PIXEL_FLOAT,PIXEL_CHAR,PIXEL_INTEGER and PIXEL_DOUBLE. Using pixel_float is fine but too memory expensive

Comment: Don't know if it helps you, but here's a PHP extension I've been working on that let you do some really sophisticated image manipulation: https://github.com/chung-leong/qb/wiki

Answer (score 5):

Use the [pack](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function:

```php
function printPacked($base, $packed_value)
{
    $value = unpack($base, $packed_value);
    printf("%08x \n", $value[1]);
}

// Unsigned char
//
$oldpixel = pack( "C", 0xFF );
printPacked("C", $oldpixel);

// Unsigned short, little-endian
//
$newpixel = pack( "v", 0xCDEF );
printPacked("v", $newpixel);

// Assign the short to the char
//
$oldpixel = $newpixel;
printPacked("C", $oldpixel);

// Mask operation on the char
//
$oldpixel = $oldpixel & pack( "C", 0xAB );                                      
printPacked("C", $oldpixel);
```

The output of the program above is:

```
000000ff 
0000cdef 
000000ef 
000000ab
```